# SAML with .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, saml

I've been given the task of working with SAML to implement an SSO solution between my company and a third party provider.  My only issue is that I can't seem to find how to implement SAML in C# 2.0.  I've been able to find a few examples for .Net 3.0 and 3.5, but none for 2.0 (and the classes they use don't appear to be available in 2.0).  Does anyone know of any oline examples using SAML and C# 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you can find a third party implementation, you are going to have to upgrade beyond v2.0. Probobly not what you want to hear, sorry...

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to be this late but I had the same problem you were having. But I've found an excellent solution in .NET 2.0 namely OIOSAML.NET (currently v. 1.4).

http://www.softwareborsen.dk/projekter/softwarecenter/brugerstyring/oiosaml.net/releases/1.4/oiosaml-dot-net-v1-4.zip